# Merge two array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

First array:

```
[{ A: 
       [ { name: '1-1',
          },
         { name: '1-2',
          } ],
      name: '1',
}]
```

Second Array:

```
[ { B: 
     [ {
         name: '1-1-1',
        },
       { 
         name: '1-1-2',
      } ],
    name: '1-1', },
  { B: 
     [ { 
         name: '1-2-1',
          },
       { 
         name: '1-2-2',
         } ],

    name: '1-2',
 } ]
```

I want The final output to be something like this:

```
[{ A: 
  [{ name: '1-1',
    B: 
     [{
        name: '1-1-1',
      },
      { 
        name: '1-1-2',
      }],
    },
   { name: '1-2',
     [{ 
       name: '1-2-1',
      },
      { 
        name: '1-2-2',
      }]
    }],
    name: '1',
}]
```

I tried using map and filter but I was using too many for loops to iterate through each and build the final result. Is there an easier way to do that?

Code I tried:

```
     var finalArray = []
            _.each(firstArray, function(itemA) {
              _.each(secondArray, function(itemB) {
                if (itemB.name === itemA.name) {
                 itemA.B = itemB.B 
//Fails here but if i do something like itemA.sjdc = 'skdjn' it comes successfully
                }
              })
              finalArray.push(itemA)
            })
```

Comment: sure updating the question with the code i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far more easier to update the first array with the corresponding items of the second array. A Map is used for getting the object with the parent names.

```js
var one = [{ A: [{ name: '1-1' }, { name: '1-2' }], name: '1' }],
    two = [{ B: [{ name: '1-1-1' }, { name: '1-1-2', }], name: '1-1' }, { B: [{ name: '1-2-1' }, { name: '1-2-2', }], name: '1-2' }],
    map = new Map(two.map(o => [o.name, o.B]));

one.forEach(({ A }) => A.forEach(o => o.B = map.get(o.name)));
    
console.log(one);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For completenes by creating new independent arrays.

```js
var one = [{ A: [{ name: '1-1' }, { name: '1-2' }], name: '1' }],
    two = [{ B: [{ name: '1-1-1' }, { name: '1-1-2', }], name: '1-1' }, { B: [{ name: '1-2-1' }, { name: '1-2-2', }], name: '1-2' }],
    map = new Map(two.map(o => [o.name, o.B]));
    merged = one.map(o =>
        Object.assign({}, o, { A: o.A.map(p =>
            Object.assign({}, p, { B: map.get(p.name) })
        ) })
    );

console.log(merged);
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```